# If party A rolls a 1 and party B rolls a 6 on their respective surprise dice how many surprise segements will party B get?

Tags: combat, adnd-1e

context:
I am playing a Solo game of Advanced Dungeons & Dragons. Trying to learn the system and doing my best to follow the rules as they are written. In the spirit of ["TheJoyofWargaming"](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CEFxthwAO7k&list=PL_z29m150g5r5TvlCLzlaBTcK7YZiTWPf&index=44&t=1538s)

My party of *hapless adventurers* (**party A**) recently wandered into an encounter with *7 giant lizards* (**party B**).

After determining distance (which happened to be 11") I next rolled for surprise.

Party A rolled a 1 (And is surprised on a 1-2...no high DEX characters here)
party B rolled a 6 (and iirc are only surprised on a 1, might need to double check MM...)

Gary doesn't explicitly exposit what to do on a 6-1 difference. So am I interpretting the rules correctly to extrapolate that the lizards get 5 segments of surprise here? Or is the surprise dice difference capped at 3 lost segments? DMG p66

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### They get 1 segment of surprise, because if only one side is surprised, the pips they rolled are the segments

This is on p. 102/103 *PH*:

> Surprise is  usually expressed as a 2 in 6 chance for all parties concerned, i.e. a six-sided die is rolled with a 1 or 2 indicating surprise. [...]
> **Each 1 of surprise equals 1 segment (six seconds) of time lost to the surprised party, and during the lost time the surprising party can freely act to escape or attack or whatever**.
> If surprise exists, the surprising party can use the time segments to flee/escape, close, or attack. Distance of 10' or less con usually be closed and an attack made in 1 segment. Physical attacks during surprise situations are also possible on o 1 per segment basis, whether the form is by weapon, projectile, or method intrinsic to the creature (claws, fangs, etc.), even a breath weapon use; magic spells require the proper number of segments of casting time, regardless of surprise.

So if only one side is suprised, there is no difference to be calculated. You straight on read how many pips the surprised side rolled, and that is the number of segments. This is also shown by an example on p. 62 *DMG*

> **Example**: *Party A is surprised on a roll of 1 or 2*, while party B is surprised only on a roll of 1. *A rolls 2* and B rolls 1, so A is inactive due to surprise for 1 segment. *Had B rolled a 2, it would not have been surprised at all, and A would have been inactive for 2 segments.* (emphasis added)

In your example, with the adventurers surprised with a 1, and the lizards not surprised with a 6, the lizards get 1 segment of surprise over the hapless adventuring party.

Comment: Well I guess the lizards got an un-earned free lunch. Bummer